# pseudo-element insert height into Div with text

Tags: html, css, layout, stylesheet, pseudo-element

I put down an example below that I have trouble with:

```
<div class="text1">Text 1</div>
<div class="text2">Text 2</div>
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/SQpdu/5/

`Text 1` has pseudo-element but the height being adjusted with the pseudo-element height.

**Requirements:**

**a.** `Text 1` height same as `Text 2` height

**b.** The red rectangle in the middle of the button.

**c.** The text must have space around them

**d.** Everything has to be `position:relative`, at least not `absolute` or `fixed` because this is just a button that could be placed anywhere.

I could just (a) remove `padding: 6px 12px;` and add `height: 30px;` but then my text won't be in the middle with space around it OR (b) add another inner `div` within `Text 1` and make that the red rectangle but I rather not add `div`.

Is there a way to work around this?

**UPDATE:** I changed the correct **link** and clarify the **requirements**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want but try this maybe helpful

```
.text1, .text2 {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    display:block;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 5px;
    height:20px;
}
.text1{
    height:28px;
   padding:0px 12px 8px 12px;
}
.text1:before {
    content:"";
    background: red;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    left: 110px;
    top: 15px;
}
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SQpdu/6/)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I think I had the wrong css code in my previous link. Can you look at my edited question again?

Answer (score 0):

You use this style code

```
.text1, .text2{
  width:120px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:30px;
}
```